# Perl running simultaneous routines

Tags: perl

I am running trying to run two sub routines at once in perl.  What is the best way I can about doing that?  For example:

```
sub 1{
        print "im running";
     }

sub 2{
        print "o hey im running too";
     }
```

How can I execute both routines at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`threads`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;

sub first {

    my $counter = shift;
    print "I'm running\n" while $counter--;
    return;
}

sub second {

    my $counter = shift;
    print "And I'm running too!\n" while $counter--;
    return;
}

my $firstThread = threads->create(\&first,15);   # Prints "I'm running" 15 times
my $secondThread = threads->create(\&second,15); # Prints "And I'm running too!" 
                                                 # ... 15 times also

$_->join() foreach ( $firstThread, $secondThread );  # Cleans up thread upon exit
```

What you should pay attention to is how the printing is interleaved irregularly. Don't try to base any calculations on the false premise that the execution order is well-behaved.

Perl threads can intercommunicate using:

- shared variables (`use threads::shared;`)
- queues (`use Thread::Queue;`)
- semaphores (`use Thread::Semaphore;`)

See [perlthrtut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html) for more information and an excellent tutorial.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423353/can-we-run-two-simultaneous-non-nested-loops-in-perl) for a related question.

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't realise that Perl can do this, but what you need is multithreading support:

http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?threads

Either that, or fork two processes, but that would be a bit harder to isolate the invocation of the subroutine.

Comment: Here's a slightly more easy to follow link: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html#Thread-Basics

Comment: d11wtq, please edit your answer: the `Thread` module (capital T) does not even work anymore, been long superseded by the `threads` module.

Comment: I edited the answer. d11wtq, I hope you don't mind, but I wanted to make sure we're not spreading any any misleading information.

Comment: Thanks and sorry on my part. I haven't used Perl since university and never needed to do any threading, it was just what came out at the top of a Google search ;) Apologies.