# Concurrent sub-routines in Perl

Tags: multithreading, perl

I am attempting to get these two sub-routines running concurrently. When I fire the program I end up with:

```
Perl exited with active threads:
    2 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

Nothing gets print onto console. I was expected while(1) to stay active until SIGTERM.

## Thread

```
use threads;

my $t1 = threads->create( \&sub2 );
my $t2 = threads->create( \&sub1 );

sub sub2 {
   my $dbh = get_connector();
   while (1) {
      print "Worker 2 Running";
      sleep 2;
   }
}

sub sub1 {
   while (1) {
      print "Worker 1 Running";
      sleep 1;
   }
}
```

Can you spot the defect here!

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue but I can spot one defect...your code doesn't compile. You're missing a semicolon after the `print` in `sub1`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2949967/perl-running-simultaneous-routines). use strict; use warnings;

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It was typo while constructing this post. Nice spot though! ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never wait for the children to end before exiting the process. Add

```
$_->join for threads->list;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set

```
$| = 1;
```

to have unbuffered output, and make sure that your main thread does something while other thread are executing, ie.

```
sleep 1 while 1;
```

or wait for threads as @ikegami suggested

```
$_->join for $t1, $t2;
```