# How can I share data between threads?

Tags: perl, multithreading

I want to share data between two threads. How can we do that?

Give some simple program.

Comment: Regarding the edit: Why? You just declare a variable shared and use it like any other variable. Where is the problem?

Comment: See [Can we run two simultaneous non-nested loops in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423353/can-we-run-two-simultaneous-non-nested-loops-in-perl/2423413#2423413) for an example.

Comment: smells awfully like homework!

Answer (score 2):

[`perldoc perlthrtut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html) contains some excellent examples on how to use threads, shared variables, semaphores and queues.

Answer (score 1):

Use `threads::shared`. See [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html).